# Replace propertyName with their getMethod

Tags: eclipse

In my class I want to get value of bean properties. I used the property name instead of calling their `geMethod()`. Is there any way to replace all the properties to their corresponding `getMethod()`.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried Find/Replace in workspace (Ctrl+F)?

Comment: In (Ctrl+F) i want to change separately each and every property. Is it possible dynamically to convert all the property name to their get method

Comment: Is it for the same class only or for the whole project?

Comment: Same class only even in a single method only

Comment: Is there any regular expression to replace property name to their corresponding getMethod()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the property & do a right click on it.

A menu will be open. In that you should be able to find and select an option called **Refactor(Alt+Shift+T)**. In that, select **Encapsulate Field**.

A popup will be open like the following:

[image]

Here provide, getter-setter names, in "Field access in declaring type", select "use setter and getter" & click OK.
It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much.solves my problem.But Here i can able to do only for single property. I have more than thirty properties.Is there any way to do for multiple property

Comment: @MonickaAkilan Sorry no idea for that.